# Driver's symbolic link disappearing

Tags: c++, driver, msdn, wdf, umdf

In my UMDF windows driver I create a symbolic link of my device in `\DosDevices\Global\` directory in order to track device instances. So if a device gets connected to the host a symbolic link `\DosDevices\Global\MyDevice0` gets created. If another device gets connected a symbolic link `\DosDevices\Global\MyDevice1` gets created. I achieve this by following code:

```
int symbolicLinkIndex = 0;
for (symbolicLinkIndex = 0; symbolicLinkIndex < 127; symbolicLinkIndex++) // 127 max usb devices
{
    swprintf(m_SymbolicLinkName,
             L"\\DosDevices\\Global\\MyDevice%d",
             symbolicLinkIndex);

    hr = m_FxDevice->CreateSymbolicLinkA(m_SymbolicLinkName);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // Symbolic link already exists try next index
        if (HRESULT_CODE(hr) == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS || HRESULT_CODE(hr) == ERROR_FILE_EXISTS)
            continue;
        else
        {
            TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, TRACE_DEVICE, "%!FUNC! Failed to create symbolic link: %lu", hr);
            goto Exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DEVICE, "%!FUNC! Created symbolic link: %S", m_SymbolicLinkName);
        break;
    }
}
```

Method documentation: [IWDFDevice::CreateSymbolicLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557023(v=vs.85).aspx)

This works if I quickly connect two devices behind each other. However it seems if I wait for about 10 seconds and connect a third device it gets the symbolic link `\DosDevices\Global\MyDevice0` which shall not happen, because the first device already got index `0` and is still connected.

So why does it seem that the symbolic link gets deleted after some while? Also I am wondering if my approach is a good one to count device instances?

Comment: What do u mean by disappearing? After some time without doing anything it is getting removed, did u mean that? Or  Is it  getting overlapped? Does it happen only on inserting the third device?

Comment: Yes I mean that it gets removed. I cannot verify the exact time when it happens. But it already happened when the third reader was inserted.